# How can i disable CC section in Publish a major Version Approval Workflow?

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, approval-process, content-approval, sharepoint-email

I want to hide these sections , but every person can change the workflow. So how to hide this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The **Approval Workflow forms** are **InfoPath** forms that can be modified using Infopath Designer.

**To modify the form do the following:**

- Open the SharePoint Designer
- Connect to your Site.
- Got to Workflow > Click on the Approval Workflow.
- In `forms` Section,> Click on the form to open and edit it with InfoPath.

[image]

- Now, you can remove the CC field or hide it as mentioned at [Hide a control based on values on the form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-a-control-based-on-values-on-the-form-0cfd584f-8e52-479d-9419-df2c4231d72e#bm3)